# Create a Cognito Test User with command line arguments error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terminal, amazon-cognito

SO I am getting a very strange problem when working with aws 
I have configured everything according to this tutorial:

https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/login-with-aws-cognito.html

Now the issue that arises is when I tried to create a mock user account. I enter the following into my macOs terminal :

```
aws cognito-idp sign-up \
  --region ca-central \
  --client-id 2rj7d9i1mcovi6vv9jbo0njeq3 \
  --username admin@example.com \
  --password passwordTrial
```

Now I get the following error:

[image]

SO far I have tried the following:

Configured my region to match my user pool, and the command presented above. This is ca-central.
I run the following:

ce[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok SO the issue was that I was missing the -1 after the region.

should have been

```
--region ca-central-1 \
```

But Now I have another error:

zsh: no matches found: passwordTrial